# node.js - can someone explain this callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js

There's more than one node.js tutorial out there, demonstrating how to create a server.  But, they're coded in different ways.  So, how do you know when to write it one way, versus another?  None of the tutorials explain ***why*** they wrote it the way they did.

For example...

Example 1:

```
// Create an http server, passing in a function for some reason:
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
```

versus Example 2:

```
// Create an http server, and then start it
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);
server.listen(PORT, function () {
```

Thanks in advance.  I'm really having trouble understanding this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're no different, really. In the first, you're defining the function for handling a request on the spot then have to start listening at the end.

```
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  ...
}).listen(PORT, function() { ... });
```

In the second, you define the function for handling a request elsewhere and don't use chaining.

```
function handleRequest(request, response) {
  ...
}
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);
server.listen(PORT, function() { ... });
```

They both do the same thing. It just depends on how you want to write it.

Comment: Good!  Thanks.  I guess I was getting hung up on stuff like "then have to start listening at the end."  Like, all that stuff -- do this now, do that later -- was really messing me up.

Answer (score 1):

Preference really.

Some prefer to handle the function definition within the argument list (typical of the older documentation as well) while others prefer to pass in the name of an already defined function.

I find the second example easier to maintain and more flexible but it really boils down to preference.

Comment: The only thing I'd add beyond "it's personal preference", would be the importance of naming functions to maintain quality stack traces and help debugging. So use this instead of #1:

`http.createServer(function handleRequest(request, response) {`...